# shell script : how to avoid null character when i read values from a file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

i have many values in a file and in one line i am getting a null value. null value is coming as the last value in that file. I want to avoid null value and take the last integer value from the file. Can anyone help me with the Regular expression for doing that. i can post what i tried here.

```
value=`cat $working_tmp_dir/numbers.txt|tail -3| head -1|cut -f2 -d'='|cut -b 1-8`
```

when i tried the above i am not getting last integer value.. its giving me null.

sample values in the files are:

```
date=11052015
date=11062015
date=11092015
date=11122015
date=11192015
date=12172015
date=20160202  
date="null value coming here"
```

the space in between numbers are just format issue. 
Please help me with that.

Comment: Can you add the sample contents of the file you are parsing to your question?

Comment: edited the question with sample .. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `null`? A blank line? The word `null`? And the data you pasted in the question does not seem to be the data from the file (or files), at least according to your proposed shell command which is expecting a line of the form `something=something` (and only outputs one line). In short, a clearer problem statement, please.

Comment: a blank line.. yes the there is something like date=11052015 i just want to take value after equal and one case i am getting date = "null"

Comment: expected output should be 20160202

Answer (score 0):

You could just parse your file with `awk` to get the last line that matches the pattern.

Based on your sample output update you could this if the line begin with `date=`

```
value=$(awk '/date=[0-9]/{a=$0}END{print a}' $working_tmp_dir/numbers.txt | grep -oP "\d+")
```

This will find lines that start with a number and set it to a variable `a` it will do this for each match and as a result the last match will be the final value set to the variable.

Also you could do this:

```
value=$(tail -n2 $working_tmp_dir/numbers.txt | grep -m1 -oP "(?<=date=)\d+$")
```

So based on the sample input this would set the variable `value` to `20160202`.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` command should work:

```
awk -F= '$2+0 == $2{n=$2} END{print n}' file

20160202
```

`$2+0 == $2` will be true only if `$2` represents a number.

Comment: If you want a variable in shell then use: `num=$(awk -F= '$2+0 == $2{n=$2} END{print n}' file)`

Comment: no anubhava.. i am trying still not getting the value.. i am doing a data load to hive tables using this value. so i am using the date as partition key and i am getting error because i get null value as partition. still i am getting null.  if the last line is like date="some character"  will it work in the above solution ?? i am trying for all day now. i have to find a solution for this.

Comment: Yes it will ignore `date="some character"` line and output previous number `20160202`

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why the following isn't sufficient?

```
egrep '^[0-9]+$' your_file | tail -1
```

You simply filter the lines with just integers on them with grep and pick the last one with tail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments.. i tried everything which you guys has posted and also did some changes myself and learned a lot things from  you guys.. thank you so much . atlast i tried this and i got the solution

```
value=`grep -Po "=\d+" $working_tmp_dir/numbers.txt |tail -1| sed 's/=//'`
```

this is perfectly working for  me....